# I need a little help with Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, attributes, product-attribute

I have a lot of products in my store more than 52000, the products was structured by category, I mean the Brand is category and the Model is a category. Now I want to have attributes instead category. Exist a solution to create this brand and model attribute and copy the value from category? So all I need is to have 2 attributes Brand and Model with the same values as categories. I can't do this manually because I have more than 52000. Maybe a script or something?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by magento it self
Note: Take backup first

Follow below steps

-> Create `Brand` and `Model` Attributes with values from `Catalog->Attributes->manage Attributes`
-> Assign in `Attribute sets` from `Catalog->Attributes->manage Attribute Sets`

Now,

-> Export products `System->Import/Export->Export` Select Entity type `Product`
-> Reset filter then click on `Continue` at bottom right corner

Now Edit this file, copy category field to brand and model field, keep only three column in file Sku, brand and model and save it as csv file

-> Import edited file `System->Import/Export->Import` Select Entity type `Product` ; Import Behavior `Append Complex Data`
-> upload file and click on `Check Data`
-> If no error then click on `Import`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I will check your solution and I will let you know but I think it is a good idea.